# Convert an array of integers to an array of chars

Tags: c, file

I have a file where every char is represented as a 32-bit Integer value so for e.g a file containing the word `Hello` contains

```
0000000: 4800 0000 6500 0000 6c00 0000 6c00 0000  H...e...l...l...
0000010: 6f00 0000 0000 0000                      o.......
```

How can I read this file into a string `Hello` so that every int is really a 8byte char? When i open this file in notepad or so i get

```
H   e   l   l   o // 3 spaces beween every character.
```

Comment: Which code have you tried to write?

Comment: Perhaps by reading the file as UTF-32 big endian?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557123/c-read-4-bytes-at-a-time) might be related. Read 4 bytes at a time and then extend it to only keep the 1st.

Comment: I have posted the code. The problem is i am so confused about en/decoding chars and integers.

Comment: "confused" can mean anything. Please take the [tour] and specifically read [ask]. Then, extract a [mcve] from your code and post that with a description of what you would expect and what you actually observe. In particular, don't dump you whole project's code here for others to pick the relevant pieces.

Comment: see also how to create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) instead of posting the whole code that no one will read here. And [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) is simply characters that are 32-bit long, why don't just read into a `uint32_t` array?

Comment: why being so harsh instead of just answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

if your codding is "every int is really a 8 byte" your example is not correct, because I see 4 byte (32-bit) for each letter.
But in any case you can use `fread` when buffer is uint64_t (or uint32_t for case of 4 byte):

```
uint64_t buf;
fread (&buf,sizeof(buf),1,file);
```

**Note**: here `1` is number of values, so you can use number of items in array of `uint64_t` instead of `1` and name of array instead of `buf`.

Than `uint64` need conversion to `char` and here you have options for taking any byte from 8:

- use union of `uint64_t` and `char[8]` (write to `uint64_t` and read for any bytre from char[0] to char[7]) - *for uint32_t use char[4] and indices from 0 to 3*
- use shift (if you need not low byte) of uint64_t value and assignment to char (e.g. to take high byte `char c = (char)(buf >> 56);`) - *high byte of uint32_t can be taken after right shift by 24, and of course the low byte does not require a shift*
- etc. (you can invent your own method of single byte, i.e. character, extraction)

**UPDATE**
There is the simplest example of `uint32_t` to `char` conversion:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union {
    uint32_t i;
    char c[4];
} buf32;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        perror ("Provide argument with filename");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    char ch;
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror ("Error opening file");
        return 2;
    }
    while (fread(&buf32.i,sizeof(buf32),1,f) == 1) {
      putchar(buf32.c[0]); // prints low byte
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE2**
Also read about little and big endian and see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548061/c-little-and-big-endian-confusion) it can be useful in your case

Comment: IMHO this code looks invariant in terms big endian or little endian, because you do not use value of `uint32_t i` as integer, you use it just a placeholder in `union { ... }`. And character value `char c` will probably be a member at lower memory address (closer to beginning to the file). Clever trick!

Comment: You shouldn't even need the union. With `char buf[4]`, just read directly to `buf`, and then pick out `buf[0]`.