# C, Little and Big Endian confusion

Tags: c, endianness

I try to understand C programming memory Bytes order, but I'm confuse.
I try my app with some value on this site for my output verification : [www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Endian-Byte-Order.html](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Endian-Byte-Order.html)

**For the 64bits value I use in my C program:**

```
volatile long long ll = (long long)1099511892096;
__mingw_printf("\tlong long, %u Bytes, %u bits,\t%lld to %lli, %lli, 0x%016llX\n", sizeof(long long), sizeof(long long)*8, LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX , ll, ll);

void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    unsigned char byte;
    int i, j;
    printf("\t");
    for (i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for (j=7;j>=0;j--)
        {
            byte = b[i] & (1<<j);
            byte >>= j;
            printf("%u", byte);
        }

        printf(" ");
    }
    puts("");
}
```

**Out**

```
long long,                8 Bytes,   64 bits,   -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, 1099511892096, 0x0000010000040880
80 08 04 00 00 01 00 00  (Little-Endian)
10000000 00001000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000
00 00 01 00 00 04 08 80  (Big-Endian)
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000100 00001000 10000000
```

**Tests**

```
0x8008040000010000, 1000000000001000000001000000000000000000000000010000000000000000 // online website hex2bin conv. 
                    1000000000001000000001000000000000000000000000010000000000000000 // my C app
0x8008040000010000, 1000010000001000000001000000000000000100000000010000000000000000 // yolinux.com


0x0000010000040880, 0000000000000000000000010000000000000000000001000000100010000000      //online website hex2bin conv., 1099511892096  ! OK
                    0000000000000000000000010000000000000000000001000000100010000000      // my C app,  1099511892096 ! OK
[Convert]::ToInt64("0000000000000000000000010000000000000000000001000000100010000000", 2) // using powershell for other verif., 1099511892096 ! OK          
0x0000010000040880, 0000000000000000000000010000010000000000000001000000100010000100      // yolinux.com, 1116691761284 (from powershell bin conv.) ! BAD !
```

**Problem**

yolinux.com website announce **0x0000010000040880** for **BIG ENDIAN** ! But my computer use LITTLE ENDIAN I think (Intel proc.)
and I get same value 0x0000010000040880 from my C app and from another website hex2bin converter. 
__mingw_printf(...0x%016llX...,...ll) also print 0x0000010000040880 as you can see.

Following yolinux website I have inverted my "(Little-Endian)" and "(Big-Endian)" labels in my output for the moment.

Also, the sign bit must be 0 for a positive number it's the case on my result but also yolinux result.(can not help me to be sure.)

If I correctly understand Endianness only Bytes are swapped not bits and my groups of bits seems to be correctly inverted.

It is simply an error on yolinux.com or is I missing a step about 64-bit numbers and C programming?

Comment: When you print a number using `printf` it doesn't matter if the system is big or little endian - they will print the same thing. Big/little endian is only about how the byte order is in memory

Comment: The hexadecimal representation of a number is not influenced by the bytewise representation in memory and only the latter is affected by the endianess.

Comment: @4386427, yes but I get the value with a function and a memory pointer. this could change something? I added the function.

Comment: @Aborted-Security No, you can only see the difference when you look at the memory order.

Comment: Start by dropping this obscure example, this isn't rocket science. This will do: `uint16_t u16 = 1; uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*)&u16; if(*p == 1) { puts("Little endian"); }`

Comment: @Lundin, thank's but I want Hexa human repr. for Little and Big Endian of 64Bit number, not checking my memory order, your code check if Little or Big if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Aborted-Security Human representation = Big Endian. If you want that, simply check if little endian and then print the bytes backwards, otherwise print them as in memory. Btw I took a look at that tutorial and it is bad. Someone using `char` type, literals like `0x000000000000FF00` and use bit-fields to prove a point about endianess clearly doesn't know what they are doing and never had to port code.

Comment: You just need to look at `char *swapbytes128(char *val)` to get the idea about the quality of that article. It uses a local, temporary array of pointers, then copies `char`s to pointers (how does that even compile?), and then returns the pointer to this temporary (stack-based) array. A disaster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you print some "multi-byte" integer using `printf` (and the correct format specifier) it doesn't matter whether the system is little or big endian. The result will be the same.

The difference between little and big endian is the order that multi-byte types are stored in memory. But once data is read from memory into the core processor, there is no difference.

This code shows how an integer (4 bytes) is placed in memory on my machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int u = 0x12345678;
    printf("size of int is %zu\n", sizeof u);
    printf("DEC: u=%u\n", u);
    printf("HEX: u=0x%x\n", u);
    printf("memory order:\n");
    unsigned char * p = (unsigned char *)&u;
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof u; ++i) printf("address %p holds %x\n", (void*)&p[i], p[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
size of int is 4
DEC: u=305419896
HEX: u=0x12345678
memory order:
address 0x7ffddf2c263c holds 78
address 0x7ffddf2c263d holds 56
address 0x7ffddf2c263e holds 34
address 0x7ffddf2c263f holds 12
```

So I can see that I'm on a little endian machine as the LSB (least significant byte, i.e. 78) is stored on the lowest address.

Executing the same program on a big endian machine would (assuming same address) show:

```
size of int is 4
DEC: u=305419896
HEX: u=0x12345678
memory order:
address 0x7ffddf2c263c holds 12 
address 0x7ffddf2c263d holds 34 
address 0x7ffddf2c263e holds 56 
address 0x7ffddf2c263f holds 78
```

Now it is the MSB (most significant byte, i.e. 12) that are stored on the lowest address.

The important thing to understand is that this **only** relates to "how multi-byte type are stored in memory". Once the integer is read from memory into a register inside the core, the register will hold the integer in the form 0x12345678 on **both** little and big endian machines.

Comment: Ok, I see very clearly with your code :) thank's you very much for your time. But , sorry I persist. Problematic is that you're doing well in hex for Little and Big. Two different values order ​​(to the eye and in memory), so the yolinux site was wrong? He inverted the Endian type for 64 Bit number ?

Comment: @Aborted-Security There are times when you want to swap between endianness in software. One example is when reading data from a network interface. On network interfaces data is always send with MSB first (Network Byte Order). So if you receive 4 bytes that represents an integer from a NIC and your system is little endian, you can't just write the 4 bytes to memory in the order they were received. You need to "swap" the bytes first.

Comment: Thank's you very much for this explanations.I will think about all this.

Comment: Then, yolinux use a bad approach for explain Big and Little ? 0x0000010000040880 != 0x8008040000010000.  ? values order change in memory, i want the hexa human rep of this order ... (I think)

Comment: @Aborted-Security Well, when written as `0x0000010000040880` and `0x8008040000010000` you are for sure **dealing with two different numbers** - regardless of endianness because it has nothing to do with endianness. But if you say: The **memory** contains the following hex values: `00 00 01 00 00 04 08 80` then the actual number is different on little endian and big endian. On little endian the actual number is: 0x8008040000010000 but on big endian the actual number is: 0x0000010000040880

Comment: Yes sure, you are rigth. I seem to have finally understood my 'problem' and I thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a single way to represent an integer in decimal, binary or hexadecimal format. For example, number `43981` is equal to `0xABCD` when written as hexadecimal, or `0b1010101111001101` in binary. Any other value (`0xCDAB`, `0xDCBA` or similar) represents a different number.

The way your compiler and cpu choose to store this value internally is irrelevant as far as C standard is concerned; the value could be stored as a [36-bit one's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series) if you're particularly unlucky, as long as all operations mandated by the standard have equivalent effects.

You will rarely have to inspect your internal data representation when programming. Practically the only time when you care about endiannes is when working on a communication protocol, because then the binary format of the data must be precisely defined, but even then your code will not be different regardless of the architecture:

```
// input value is big endian, this is defined
// by the communication protocol

uint32_t parse_comm_value(const char * ptr)
{
     // but bit shifts in C have the same
     // meaning regardless of the endianness
     // of your architecture

     uint32_t result = 0;
     result |= (*ptr++) << 24;
     result |= (*ptr++) << 16;
     result |= (*ptr++) << 8;
     result |= (*ptr++);
     return result;
}
```

Tl;dr calling a standard function like `printf("0x%llx", number);` always prints the correct value using the specified format. Inspecting the contents of memory by reading individual bytes gives you the representation of the data on your architecture.